# Why am I receiving a base64 encoded text file instead of the PDF file when using Lambda proxy integration in API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm facing an issue with my API Gateway configuration. I have an endpoint that is supposed to return a PDF file when accessed through a GET method. This endpoint receives a query string parameter containing the file name and passes it to a Lambda function (using proxy integration) that searches for the corresponding PDF in an S3 Bucket and returns it.

However, when I request the endpoint, instead of receiving the PDF file, I'm getting a text file with the base64-encoded content of the PDF. Here's an example of the response I'm receiving: [plain text file with PDF content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU1RH.png)

My services are setted up like this:

- In my API Gateway settings I added 'application/pdf' as binary media type.
- The method response has the default config: [method response configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLA6k.png)
- The lambda function code is:

  ```
  const S3 = require("./S3");

  exports.handler = async (event) => {

    try {
      if (!event.queryStringParameters.invoice) {
        throw new Error("must specify invoice name");
      }

      const fileName = event.queryStringParameters.invoice;

      const file = await S3.getFile(fileName);

      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
          "Content-Disposition": `attachment; filename=${fileName}`,
        },
        body: file.Body.toString("base64"),
        isBase64Encoded: true,
      };
    } catch (e) {
      return {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: JSON.stringify({ status: "error", message: e.message }),
      };
    }
  };
  ```

I discovered that changing the binary media type of the API Gateway to '*/*' resolves the issue and I receive the PDF file correctly. However, this configuration causes the responses of the other methods, which are configured with 'application/json', to return an 'Internal server error'.

I also tried adding the "Accept: application/pdf" header to the client request using Postman and it seems to work. However, I cannot add this header to a browser request, which is the intended client for my endpoint.

Is there something I'm missing here? should I switch to a non-proxy integration? what other API Gateway settings could I modify?

Any help or suggestions will be truly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue, the response was base64 string. I was working on .net core and angular. Providing the correct accept type in request, i.e. in my case application/zip, only resolve my issue. It was pretty easy on angular. None of the other solutions worked including converting response to base64 and/or setting isBase64Encoded header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying that `'*/*'` is a binary media type, you just told API gateway to treat ALL responses from all of your methods as binary. You need to add `application/pdf` as the binary media type in API Gateway, not `*/*`. Then API Gateway will see that in the response your Lambda function returns, and treat the response from that one function as binary, while leaving all the `application/json` responses from your other Lambda functions as text.